# Blank values in user form

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to get values from userform in module but it always shows blank.

EmailIdForm:

```
Private Sub CLRBTN_Click() 
    Call UserForm_Initialize
End Sub

Private Sub OKBTN_Click()
    ToInput = EmailIdForm.ToInput.Value    
    CCInput = EmailIdForm.CCInput.Value 
    Unload EmailIdForm    
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ToInput.Value = ""
    CCInput.Value = ""
    ToInput.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Module:

```
Public ToInput As String    
Public CCInput As String  

Sub EmailInput()
    EmailIdForm.Show
    MsgBox ToInput    
    MsgBox CCInput
End Sub
```

Comment: You might consider reading [this](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/).

Comment: I guess, `ToInput` in `OKBTN_Click` refers to TextBox rather public variable.

Comment: @JohnyL What changes I need to do, so that it refers to public variable?

Comment: Try to change the names of global variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the visibility of the modul level variables ToInput and CCInput. If you name the modul MyModul just add the scope to the variables variables. See the modified code here:

```
Private Sub OKBTN_Click()
    MyModul.ToInput = EmailIdForm.ToInput.Value    
    MyModul.CCInput = EmailIdForm.CCInput.Value 
    Unload EmailIdForm    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the comments;

1. 10000% read [UserForm1.Show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/). It might take some time to understand it (and a lot of googling things) but if you use UserForms it's worth the read to better understand how they work and how to work with them.
2. If you have a control on your userform with the same name as your public variable, the control will take precedence over the public variable.

So it is assumed that your `TextBox` names are `ToInput` and `CCInput` respecitvely.

When writing code in the UserForm code module, you could access these controls in 3 different ways (let's use the `ToInput` textbox in our example):

```
EmailIdForm.ToInput 'Explicitly declare which UserForm we are accessing the control on.
Me.ToInput          'The 'Me' keyword refers to that instance of the class (in the case you could have more than 1 instance of the class loaded).
ToInput             'The UserForm object is implied by it's own class.
```

[The Me Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/me-keyword)
[Avoiding implicit qualifiers](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/10/25/clean-vba-code-pt-2-avoiding-implicit-code/)

To fix your problem, you will need to [remove your naming conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/avoiding-naming-conflicts). Either rename your variables or rename your textbox controls - *or both!

Consider doing a bit of research about good practices when it comes to naming variables, controls, objects, data types etc. I like to use descriptive names so someone who doesn't already know what the codes is doing can read it and understand - but this can come at the cost of making the code quite verbose - or - dense.

Consider chaning the names like this: (**Note:** *It is entirely up to you how you name things in your code, this is just a suggestion.*)

```
Module: 
----------------------------------------
Public PublicToInputString As String
Public PublicCCInputString AS String

Sub EmailInput()
    EmailIdForm.Show
    MsgBox PublicToInputString
    MsgBox PublicCCInputString
End Sub
-----------------------------------
Userform:
-----------------------------------
Private Sub OKBTN_Click()
    PublicToInputString = Me.ToInputTextBox.Value
    PublicCCInputString = Me.CCInputTextBox.Value
    Unload Me 'Consider chaning to Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Now the code is clear and telling us what is what - Anyone could understand you are assigning a textbox value to a public variable string and following a naming convention like this also means you are far less likely to have naming conflicts - Again - **Note:** *this is not a naming convention you must follow, merely a suggestion. Everyone has their own way that works for them*.